# When PersistentVolumes are deleted on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

This question arose when we ran a `kubectl delete -f` on a file that somehow contained the declaration of the namespace where an entire test deployment existed.

The system (not configured by us, hence a bit obscure to us) had volumes provisioned by an OpenEBS system.

Within the deleted namespace there were some PVCs that had PVs provisioned on OpenEBS. When the namespace was deleted PVCs were deleted and all the PVs too.

I read quite some documentation, but I have not found an explicit answer to my question. Knowing that;

- PVs are not scoped so do not belong to any namespace
- If a PVC is deleted the bound (if present) PV is deleted only if the `reclaimPolicy` is set to `Delete`

The only case when PVs are deleted as a consequence of a namespace deletion is if the namespace contains a PVC bound to a PV with a `reclaimPolicy: Delete`. Hence all the provisioned PVs in our system had this issue. Or m I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is the actual question here. You have correctly described that if the reclaimPolicy is set to Delete then deleting the pvc will delete the associated PVs as well. So, what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the flow is like:

- when a namespace is deleted, all the objects inside this namespace is also will be deleted
- Now, if there is any PVC in that deleted namespace then it will be deleted
- According to the rules, If a PVC is deleted then it's bounded PV will also be deleted if the `reclaimPolicy` is delete.

N.B: Normally to delete a PVC first you need to delete the pods those are referencing it. And to delete a bound PV first you need to delete it's respective PVC. Deletion system is like : first pods (who are referencing that PVC) get deleted then the respective PVC and then the PV(if reclainPolicy is delete).